# scala/java incompatibility: overloaded methods with varargs

Tags: java, scala, variadic-functions, type-erasure

I have the following java code:

```
interface J {
  void f(int... a);

  void f(String... a);
}
```

How can it be overridden in scala?

I'm getting an error `double definition: method ... and ... have same type after erasure: (a: Seq)Unit` with this code:

```
class S extends J {
  def f(a: Int*) {}

  def f(a: String*) {}
}
```

Comment: Probably you can implement them as methods with `Array`s, not varargs.

Comment: AFAIK only by also changing the Java interface, Scala also expects varargs when Java requires them. Tim, can you change the Java interface to reflect that? If you do not have the Java interface under control, you can create a wrapper in Java that provides two method names and delegates to Scala, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132089/how-to-implement-java-interface-in-scala-with-multiple-variable-parameter-method

Comment: @Elmar, sadly, but the interface resides in a third-party library, and moreover, the class is also supposed to be used by that library.

Comment: @timzh but the solution provided in the link would work in that case then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132089/how-to-implement-java-interface-in-scala-with-multiple-variable-parameter-method

Comment: @ElmarWeber, yes, my mistake, it will work indeed.